# Unable to launch DAML studio

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, daml

On MacOs, when I try to launch daml studio from command line, I receive several errors and it doesn't launch.

I have gone through all the installation requirements for DAML including installing Visual Studio Code which runs successfully on my Mac as well as the latest Java SDK.  I went through the quickstart and DAML successfully works on my system using the IOU on http://localhost:4000.  I updated %PATH correctly and have gone through the instructions twice to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Here is what I launch and the results that it is providing...

```
MacBook-Pro-2:quickstart aron.elston$ daml studio
/bin/sh: code: command not found

Failed to install DAML Studio extension from marketplace.
Installing bundled DAML Studio extension instead.
/bin/sh: code: command not found

Failed to install DAML Studio extension from SDK bundle.
Please open an issue on GitHub with the above message.
https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/issues/new?template=bug_report.md
/bin/sh: code: command not found

Failed to launch DAML studio. Make sure Visual Studio Code is installed.
See https://code.visualstudio.com/Download for installation instructions.

MacBook-Pro-2:quickstart aron.elston$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/aron.elston/.daml/bin
MacBook-Pro-2:quickstart aron.elston$ pwd
/Users/aron.elston/.daml/bin/quickstart
MacBook-Pro-2:quickstart aron.elston$
```

I would expect it to open the project in Visual Studio Code but instead I get errors as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `code` command to launch VS code isn't available on the command line. That should be fixable by following the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Comment: Note that it is not necessary for `code` to be in `PATH`. We will look it up in `/Applications` on `MacOS`. The step that was missing here is probably step 3 of https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_installation.